# How to dequeue or deregister specific woocoomerce script in wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove Woocommerce script: **wc-admin-order-meta-boxes-js** *(woocommerce/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.min.js)* from the edit-order page or all admin pages in woocommerce. I tried everything but nothing works. Can anyone help me? Thanks.
For example, I tried this:

```
    add_action( 'admin_print_script', 'remove_admin_scripts', 1 );
     function remove_admin_scripts() {
    // Dequeue
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-admin-order-meta-boxes-js' );

    // Deregister
    wp_deregister_script( 'wc-admin-order-meta-boxes-js' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the wrong name of the script. You can just dequeue as it is enqueued, but with a higher priority.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_admin_scripts', 99 );
function remove_admin_scripts() {
    // Dequeue.
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-admin-order-meta-boxes' );
    // Deregister.
    wp_deregister_script( 'wc-admin-order-meta-boxes' );
}
```

This is tested and works.